# An alternative to List.Contains for custom classes

Tags: list, contains, path-finding

I'm trying to do a pathfinding with A* and made a class "Node".

The point is that i have a list of Nodes and i need to know if a Node is already in the list, but List.Contains doesn't work.

Btw, i need to compare the world position which is in a variable inside Node and i don't know how to override the List.Contains to compare with that variable.

Edit: Added the Node class trying to implement Equals and HashSet

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Node {

public Node parentNode;

public int nodeX;
public int nodeY;
public Vector2 nodePosition;

public bool state;

public int gCost;
public int hCost;
public int fCost;

public Node(int x, int y){
    nodeX = Mathf.RoundToInt(x);
    nodeY = Mathf.RoundToInt(y);
    nodePosition = new Vector2(nodeX, nodeY);
}

public void SetCost(Node end){
    if(parentNode != null){
        gCost =(int) parentNode.gCost + 10;
    }
    else{
        gCost = 10;
    }

    hCost =(int) (Mathf.Abs(nodeX - end.nodeX) + Mathf.Abs(nodeY-end.nodeY));
    fCost =(int) gCost + hCost;
}

public bool Equals (Node other){
    if(other == null){return false;}
    if(this.nodePosition == other.nodePosition){return true;}
    else{return false;}

}

public override bool Equals(Object other){
    if(other == null){return false;}
    if(other is Node){
        return this.Equals(other);
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public override int GetHashCode(){
    return nodeX ^ nodeY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the open set, you should be using a [priority queue](https://github.com/BlueRaja/High-Speed-Priority-Queue-for-C-Sharp).  For the closed set, just add a property `HasBeenVisited` to every node.  You don't need a `List` for A*.

Comment: The problem is when i'm looking for the neighbour nodes i create them. And because of that, the only way to not creating a new one if there is a node with the same position i don't really know how to compare if the Node that is going to be created has already a Node in that position.

But about priority queue i didn't see anything so i'll check it

Comment: In that case you probably want a `HashSet`.  You'll have the same issue with equivalent nodes not being considered equal, so look up how to correctly implement `Equals` and `IEquatable<T>`

Comment: That's what i have been doing. But i can't see anywhere a decent explanation of how to override Equals and HashSet. I have tried it already and doesn't work but i don't know if i'm doing something bad so i'll edit the question and add the Node class code.

Comment: @Luxgile: Please post it to codereview.SE, there are too many problems with that code to enumerate here.  I believe your main issue is with `return this.Equals(other);` not casting to `Node`

Comment: Sry but i don't actually know what's codereview.SE. And i hope when you say many problems you talk about the override functions and that stuff...